# Windows Service C#: Accessing Mail. The Autodiscover service couldn't be located

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have tried both the methods below but both return the result "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg591267(v=EXCHG.140).aspx

```
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userData.EmailAddress, userData.Password);

  if (userData.AutodiscoverUrl == null)
  {
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(userData.EmailAddress, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
    userData.AutodiscoverUrl = service.Url;
  }
  else
  {
    service.Url = userData.AutodiscoverUrl;
  }

  return service;
}
```

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Exchange-2013-Set-pull-14c8360b#content

```
static ExchangeService GetBinding()
        {
            // Create the binding.
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);

        // Define credentials.
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("myemail@work.com", "password");

        // Use the AutodiscoverUrl method to locate the service endpoint.
        try
        {
            service.AutodiscoverUrl("myemail@work.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
        }
        catch (AutodiscoverRemoteException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown: " + ex.Error.Message);
        }

        // Display the service URL.
        Console.WriteLine("AutodiscoverURL: " + service.Url);
        return service;
    }
```

In the one instance I enter my email and password, in the other its hard-coded. Both hang when attempting Autodiscoverurl and eventually fail with the message "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located." I added the references as per the tutorials and Autodiscover appears under Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll ... Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Is the autodiscover service definitely running?

Comment: @MattWhetton How can I check if it is running?

Comment: This article details some information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc539050.aspx - but you can also log onto the exchange server and look in IIS - see if you can find it and its running.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

after you set the credentials

Comment: I tried this but same result "The Autodiscover service couldn't be located"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have resolved it yet, I bumped into your post as I was searching for a solution for the same (or similar?) problem.

The peculiar thing was:
Since it worked perfectly in Debug mode, but not once installed as Windows service, I changed the 'Log On' settings in the Windows Service Properties (services.msc, right click on installed service, Properties, Log On Tab) and set it to 'Local System account' and checked the 'Allow service to interact with desktop' option.

That did the trick for me.